# iOS calling function on location change throwing an exception

Tags: ios

I have a class A that declares an initialize function as shown below. This is called from AppDelegate `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Now when the application goes to the background, I am capturing the user's current location. When the application comes to the foreground, I get the new location and if the user has moved more than a given distance, I want to call initialize again which pops the `mainviewcontroller` and recalculates data.

I am getting an exception in the line `mvc = ...`. If I set the "Application does not run in background" to `YES` then initialize is getting called with no issues (if I remove calling the initialize based on distance.). Any help would be much appreciated!

Exception is:

`[_UIModalItemAppViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I have:

```
....
UINavigationController *n ;
MainViewController *mvc;
....
....

+(void)refetch
{

static BOOL initialized = NO;
 n = (UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
 mvc = (MainViewController *)[n viewControllers][0];

if (!initialized)
{
    initialized = YES;
    calculatedValuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self updateLocation];
    [self fetchData];
}
}
```

Comment: Never call `initialize` yourself. It is a standard Objective-C method that will be called by the runtime the 1st time there is any reference to the class.

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that it is enough to move the recalculation to another function and call that one instead?

Comment: Perhaps. But it seems, from the error, that the `rootViewController` isn't what you think it is. It seems if your app is loaded in the background, the `rootViewController` is some private class, not your expected nav controller.

Comment: @rkh The name of the method isn't really the cause of this specific problem. But your should not call your method that.

Comment: `initialize` is a class method, so `self` is the class. That is probably not what you want. Do your work in an _instance_.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson guys, I changed the function to refetch and I am looking into Leo's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `keyWindow` is not the window you are expecting and it contains private view hierarchy. Try instead to use the app delegate's window: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window`.

Comment: Thanks Leo. When I changed it I got another error: `-[UIWindow viewControllers]: unrecognized selector`

Comment: @rkh You forgot to call `.rootViewController`. ;)

Comment: :) what a mistake. Thanks for the quick response and catch!

Answer (score -1):

Problem is here:

```
n = (UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
 mvc = (MainViewController *)[n viewControllers][0];
```

Variable `n` don't have ivar `viewControllers`.

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the question. 2) This code make no attempt to access an ivar named `viewController`. It attempts to call a method named `viewController`. And normally this should work because the code assumes that the root view controller actually is a `UINavigationController`.